# Typescript hello world error in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, typescript

I'm trying to get a very basic hello world working on Typescript & Visual studio 2012. In the test method, I want to declare a parameter of one of the interfaces in module. What am I missing ?

```
module Demo {
    interface Person {
        Name: string;
        Addresses: Address[];
    }

    interface Employee extends Person {
        Salary: number;
    }

    interface Address {
        Street: string;
    }
}

import D = Demo;

function greeter(person: string) {
    return "Hello, " + person;
}

function test(a: D.Address)
{

}
```

I get this Error :

> 20    The property 'Address' does not exist on value of type 'Demo'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should "export" class/interface to use it:

```
module Demo {
    export interface Address {
        Street: string;
    }
}
```